# Can you have two different fulfillment's in the dialogflow inline editor?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I was following the Dialogflow tutorial for appointment booking at the "bike shop" (if you haven't heard of it, I'll post the link to the tutorial, I used the exact same sample code with the only difference being the API credentials).

I had pasted/ combined the other tutorial code for the weather sample right under, but then the bike shop booking stops working and the weather is the only one that works.

Is the inline editor on Dialogflow only meant to be able to handle only 1 type of fulfillment or am I doing something wrong?

**Links:**

Bike shop- https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-bike-shop-nodejs

Weather Sample- https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-weather-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the line

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
```

from both projects do the same thing - they create a webook URL with the path ending in "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment".

It isn't clear why you want both code blocks in the same inline fulfillment editor or what, exactly, you're trying to accomplish. But if you want to handle the same Intents, you need to copy the content of this `onRequest` block selectively to get the Intent handlers you need.